# Issues with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I started creating my app with min SDK 15 and I used the v4 support library for the fragments and the fragment manager and fragment transaction etc. When I decided to use card animations, I figured I had to switch to using the fragments without the support library. But when I did this, once I press the back button, the whole app closes instead of returning to the previous view. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Let's see some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by extending only activity instead of the support deprecated ActionBarActivity.